# Flex cachy problem

Tags: apache-flex, flex3

I am querying to server through flex,first time its show the result but when I insert a new record and query next time,its shows previous results only(problem facing in IE but not in chrome).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can parametrize your http(?) request, and by setting an always changing parameter, you can make sure that your response never gets read from cache.
In the examples below I use a parameter with the name `nocache` for this task:

You can set the `nocache` parameter in your url string:

```
var url:String = "http://data.your.server?nocache=" + new Date().getTime();
```

Or -if you use a `URLRequest`, you can set it inside its data member:

```
//the url from where you get the data
var url:String = "http://data.your.server";

var urlVars:URLVariables = new URLVariables();
urlVars.nocache = new Date().getTime();
//set the other parameters (if any)

//attach the parameter list to your request
var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest(url);
request.data = urlVars;
```

**Update**
Here the `new Date().getTime()` will return the system's current time in milliseconds, so this way you can be sure, that it won't get called with this parameter value again.

Answer (score 0):

That's because IE caches your request.

Add a random query string parameter to the remote URL you use, like `http://myserver.com/fetch_data?random=4234324`

(And by random I don't mean use 4234324 all the time, use actionscript to generate a random number and append it to the url)

See [this KB from adobe](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/159/tn_15951.html)